# How to set telnet start after every reboot in suse 11sp3 x64

Tags: linux, opensuse, telnet, sles

I have an issue on sles 11sp3x64 with telnet, if i reboot the machine telnet service not starting automatically. again i have to do service restart manually. is there any way to start automaticaly after every reboot.

Thanks,

Comment: are you aware that `telnet` is not secure and people replaced it with `ssh` during the last quarter of the 20th century?

Comment: ya i know that but for my requirement telnet is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Enable telnetd in xinetd. This can be done manually by editing /etc/xinetd.conf and changing disabled = yes to disabled = no, or by using the following command:
chkconfig telnetd on

Start xinetd if its not running already.
/etc/init.d/xinetd start

Make sure that xinetd is started automatically at boot time
chkconfig xinetd on

Or you could add an entry in /etc/rc.local file. Any command in that file is executed at the end of the bootup process. 
So you could put this line: /etc/init.d/telnetd start
at the end of your /etc/rc.local